# How to read a character array of a name, without reading white space?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++ and I have a dynamic char array with a max size of 30.  I need to extract the name from the array into a string but i have no way of knowing how long the name is.

For example someone named Bob should look like:
  Bob____________________    (_ is blank space)

but it instead reads like:
   Bob%#$*(%*$#)%@#*#@$$#

or something of the sort.  I know its doing that because its just random unasigned memory, but how can i cut it off at the end of bob so i can add the blank spaces manually?

In case it is unclear i am reading the letters character by character using a for loop that runs 30 times exactly.

this is my current loop

```
string n = "";
  for(int i=0; i<MAX_NAME_LEN; i++)
  {
     n += name[i];
  }
```

In this case n should be equal to "Bob___________________"

but it is Bob and a bunch of random crap as stated earlier.

Comment: Where are you getting this array from?

Comment: I created it.  It is char *name = new char[30];

Comment: Where's it getting its input from? Why is it not null terminated? Why isn't it a `std::string`?

Comment: OK null terminated is not someething i am familar with,  i assume that would be like ending the loop when it reaches white space.  Could you explain this to me?

Comment: End the loop when it reaches white space.

Comment: @Josh: are you familiar with google search?

Comment: To be clear the root of your issue is in the code you aren't showing, I have the sneaking suspicion you have zero need for the `char` array in the first place, but if you don't know what a null terminated string is then I suggest you read the first few chapters of an [introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: haha you are right.  I transfered schools and here all coding is in C++ which i have never done before whereas i have already learned years of java so theres a lot of things they expect us to know from previous years which i have never heard of before.

Comment: From what i have researched the way i see it is i should check if the current value is 0 and if so break the loop. Thank you

Comment: how about `string n(name)` ?

Comment: First you should take a look at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

Comment: Thank you!  That literally explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

IF you read this caracters from a array of char so a C string you can do something like this(it should be a null terminated string '\0').

```
n = std::string(name)
```

And affter that you can add the number of time your want a white space in your string. In my code I want a 30 caracter max with the name included. So it can be someting like that.

```
if(n.size() < 30)
    n = n + std::string(30-n.size(), ' ');
```